# What will be the translation of ms Sql query to oracle

Tags: oracle, database-migration, datediff

sql query is:

```
Declare @Calculation DECIMAL=ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@NowTime,@ShiftStartTime))/DATEDIFF(SECOND,'00:00:00.0000',@TaktTime)
```

here NowTime, ShiftStartTime and TaktTime are timestamp variable and Calculation is number format..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide values of input variable you are using...

Comment: in ms sql : with time(7) data type, NowTime:13:30:00.0000000, ShiftStartTime:06:00:00.0000000,TaktTime:14:30:00.0000000

Comment: I want to map time(7) from sql  with timestamp of oracle

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> declare
  2    NowTime        date := to_date('2010-11-18 23:45:12', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
  3    ShiftStartTime date := to_date('2010-11-18 22:44:40', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
  4    TaktTime       date := to_date('2020-01-01 00:03:11', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
  5  begin
  6    dbms_output.put_line('Result = ' || (TaktTime - trunc(TaktTime)) / (NowTime - ShiftStartTime));
  7  end;
  8  /

Result = ,05258810572687224669603524229074
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not have a `TIME` data type - it has `DATE` (Days to integer seconds precision) and `TIMESTAMP(9)` (Days to up-to nano-second precision). If you are going to use `TIME(7)` and fractional seconds then you want to use `TIMESTAMP(7)` and then differences will be calculated using Oracle's `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type:

```
DECLARE
  NowTime        TIMESTAMP(7) := SYSTIMESTAMP; -- TIMESTAMP '2018-01-22 13:30:00.0000000';
  ShiftStartTime TIMESTAMP(7) := TIMESTAMP '2018-01-22 06:00:00.0000000';
  TaktTime       TIMESTAMP(7) := TIMESTAMP '2018-01-22 14:30:00.0000000';

  ShiftLength    INTERVAL DAY(3) TO SECOND(7) := NowTime - ShiftStartTime;
  TaktLength     INTERVAL DAY(3) TO SECOND(7) := TaktTime - TRUNC( TaktTime );

  Value NUMBER;
BEGIN
  Value := ABS(
             (
               EXTRACT( DAY    FROM ShiftLength ) * 24 * 60 * 60
               EXTRACT( HOUR   FROM ShiftLength )      * 60 * 60
               EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM ShiftLength )           * 60
               EXTRACT( SECOND FROM ShiftLength )
             )
             /
             (
               EXTRACT( DAY    FROM TaktLength ) * 24 * 60 * 60
               EXTRACT( HOUR   FROM TaktLength )      * 60 * 60
               EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM TaktLength )           * 60
               EXTRACT( SECOND FROM TaktLength )
             )
           );
END;
/
```